# Названия деревень

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

В деревне Удалая или Удалой, Троицкая или Троицкой? В д. Сиуха , в д. Громовка — правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Если род имени собственного совпадает с родом имени нарицательного, обозначающего основное понятие, то этот топоним склоняется. В ваших примерах все имена собственные женского рода и относятся к слову *деревня* (тоже женского рода). Значит, они будут иметь такой же падеж, как и основное понятие: *В деревне Удалой, в деревне Троицкой*. В следующих двух примерах склонение топонимов тем более обязательно, потому что в них  слово, обозначающее основное понятие, сокращено: В д. Сиухе , в д. Громовке.

**За последнюю неделю это уже третий вопрос на одну и ту же тему.** Был вопрос о склонении названий городов, о склонении названий сёл. Теперь деревни. Читайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы вопросы, имеющие сходные метки.